# How to get Sub folder name using Test ID in HP QC OTA Java

Tags: java, hp-quality-center, com4j

Actually need to get SubFolder name using Test ID which is present under

> Test Plan > Subject > Sample(Folder Name) > Scenario (Sub Folder) >
>   TC1 (Test- BPT)

I need to retrieve `Scenario` as subfolder name using `TestID`

Here is my code

```
ITestSetTreeManager tstm = tdc.testSetTreeManager().queryInterface(ITestSetTreeManager.class);   
ITestSetFolder tsf = tstm.nodeByPath("Root\\Lab").queryInterface(ITestSetFolder.class); 

    IList testSets = tsf.findTestSets("Regression", false, "");   

    for (Com4jObject testSetObj : testSets)   
    {   
        ITestSet testSet = testSetObj.queryInterface(ITestSet.class);   

        System.out.println(testSet.name());   
        IBaseFactory testFactory = testSet.tsTestFactory().queryInterface(IBaseFactory.class);   
        IList testInstances = testFactory.newList("");   
        for (Com4jObject testInstanceObj : testInstances)   
        {   
            ITSTest testInstance = testInstanceObj.queryInterface(ITSTest.class);   
            System.out.println(testInstance.testName());
            Object ID =  testInstance.testId();
            System.out.println(ID.toString());
         }
    }
```

Using ID object I could be able to retrieve `TestId` and also I need to retrieve the sub folder name.

For that tried with TS_SUBJECT but it fails

Can anyone share your views on fetching sub folder name / TS_SUBJECT field value.

Answer (score 0):

Finally retrieved the Folder (Sub folder) name of current Business Process Test by using `ISubjectNode` using java Com4jObject

```
ITestFactory iTestFactory = QCConnection.testFactory().queryInterface(ITestFactory.class);
Com4jObject comobjTest = iTestFactory.item(testInstance.testId());
ITest iTest = comobjTest.queryInterface(ITest.class);
Com4jObject SubjectField = (Com4jObject)iTest.field("TS_SUBJECT");
ISubjectNode SubFolder = SubjectField.queryInterface(ISubjectNode.class);
System.out.println(SubFolder.Name());
```